# In Lift, how do I select the top-level element in repeated (auto-duplicated) CssSel transform

Tags: scala, lift

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="top_level">
   ... other elements ...
</div>
```

and I want the output to result in a sequence of DIV:

```
<div id="1" class="top_level">
   ... other elements ...
</div>
<div id="2" class="top_level">
   ... other elements ...
</div>
<div id="3" class="top_level">
   ... other elements ...
</div>
```

I am trying to do this via a CssSel transform where the nested elements themselves will be looped over (there is a table inside the div), so I have something akin to:

```
".top_level *" #> groups.map(group =>
  ".top_level [id]" #> group.id & // WHAT CSS Selector can I use? 
  ".the_row *" #> group.rows.map( ... )
  )
```

It all works fine, other than the ID does not get set. I can see that my selector ".top_level [id]" is nested, and therefore it makes sense that it doesn't work, but I cannot think of what else to put there to get the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to repeat your .top_level element, while adding an id to each node and further processing the contents.  You can cut and paste it into the REPL to play around with it.

```
scala> import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._

scala> val html = <div class="top_level">
     |   <table>
     |     <tr>
     |       <td>Cell</td>
     |     </tr>
     |   </table>
     | </div>
html: scala.xml.Elem = 
<div class="top_level">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


scala> val data = List(("id1", "cell 1"), ("id2", "cell 2"))
data: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((id1,cell 1), (id2,cell 2))

scala> val sel = ".top_level" #> {
     |   data map { d =>
     |     ".top_level [id]" #> d._1 &
     |     "td *" #> d._2
     |   }
     | }
sel: net.liftweb.util.CssSel = CssBind(Full(.top_level), Full(ClassSelector(top_level,Empty))) 

scala> sel.apply(html)
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = 
NodeSeq(<div class="top_level" id="id1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>, <div class="top_level" id="id2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>)
```

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. I thought you had to use a * in a selector that was going to be repeated (but which also designated the content). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One other answer is to restructure the code as follows:

```
def listXform(itemTemplate : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
  val iterableXform = for(t <- list;
      a <- t.optionalElement;
      b <- a.optionalElement
     ) yield {
     (".top_level [id]" #> a.id &
     // other bits
     ).apply(itemTemplate)
  }

  iterableXform.foldLeft(NodeSeq.Empty)( (a,b) => a ++ b)
}

def render(seq : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = listXform(seq)
```

but in light of my earlier misunderstanding, this is less optimal.

Comment: There might be a cleaner solution, but it's difficult to tell what your'e trying to accomplish.  Adding an example of what the output should look like would help.

Comment: @DaveWhittaker Hi Dave. I have a nested element I'm repeating, and I need to assign an "id" attribute to it, but I don't want to wrap it in an extra senseless div just to do so. I'd like to be able to say: ".element *" #> list.map(item => ".element [id]" #> item.id)

Comment: What I don't understand is, if it's a nested element that you are repeating (nested inside the .top_level div) then top level wouldn't be repeated, so I don't understand the attempt to add an id attribute to it.  If you are repeating .top_level itself, then why the ".top_level *" match?  That's why I think an example of what you want your output to look like would be helpful.

Comment: @DaveWhittaker I edited my question to be a simpler expression of what I seek.